# XSLT transforming a file defined in ASCII that contains Unicode character entities

Tags: xml, character-encoding, xslt-1.0, non-ascii-characters, character-entities

I'm trying to process an XML file that claims (correctly I believe) to be encoded in 7-bit ASCII itself, but it contains text values that include character entities like `&#215;` that resolve to Unicode characters.

The problem is (I think) is that the processor (the version of Xalan bundled with Treebeard) is resolving the character entities and turning them into gobbledegook before the XSLT stylesheet even gets to touch the content.

I've put together a stripped-down test case below-

**XML Input Data**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ascii"?>
<root>
   <unit Code="[Btu_39]" CODE="[BTU_39]" isMetric="no" class="heat">
      <name>British thermal unit at 39&#160;&#176;F</name>
      <printSymbol>Btu<sub>39&#176;F</sub>
      </printSymbol>
      <property>energy</property>
      <value Unit="kJ" UNIT="kJ" value="1.05967">1.05967</value>
   </unit>
</root>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

    <xsl:variable name="sep" select='";"' />
    <xsl:variable name="mult" select='"&#215;"' />
    <xsl:variable name="crlf" select='"&#13;&#10;"' />
    <xsl:variable name="lf" select='"&#10;"' />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="name printSymbol value" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/*">
        Type: <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        Code: <xsl:value-of select="@Code" />
        CODE: <xsl:value-of select="@CODE" />
        Description: <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
        Print: <xsl:apply-templates select="printSymbol" />
        Property: <xsl:apply-templates select="property" />
        Value: <xsl:apply-templates select="value" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$lf" />       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name|printSymbol|property">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@value, $mult, @Unit, $lf)" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output- Note the degree symbols (for deg. F) are mangled**

```
Type: unit
Code: [Btu_39]
CODE: [BTU_39]
Description: British thermal unit at 39Â Â°F
Print: Btu
Property: energy
Value: 1.05967Ã—kJ
```

I've found similar questions to this in the programming sections, and one answer has been to pre-process the input file to escape or encode the character entities, but in this case i'm using XSLT "bare" with no other languaage involved, so a pure XSLT solution is really what i need.

Ideas or links to answers much appreciated.

--UPDATE--
MY initial guess was wrong. Some experimenting with other output formats shows that (for example) with the output method set to HTML, the problem characters are output as HTML entities. This indicates the characters *are* making it into the translation unmangled. I assume it must be the output processing causing the problem.

As requested I have taken a small chunk of the text (the "at 39 °F" part of the name element) and dumped the hex of the input and output strings.

[image: hex analysis of a piece of the text]

--UPDATE--
Some digging showed that-

1. The original tool (Treebeard) was transforming the output to UTF-8,
   but then: (a) Displaying it incorrectly (I think as cp1252); (b)
   Transforming the output to cp1252 when writing the output to a file.
2. The second tool (Simple XSLT Transform) was displaying the utf8 output correctly on-screen, but still transforming to cp1252 when writing to disk.
3. A [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding#362006) on this site confirmed that Java picks up a default file encoding when it starts up. As both tools are written in Java this was causing the file output problem.

I followed the recommendation in that thread to set up a windows environment variable as follows: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Success!

The file is written to utf8 and can be opened successfully in either Notepad++ or Excel (PowerQuery). You have to manually set the "cp65001" code page in PowerQuery, but it works.

Thank you to those who replied, you helped get me on the right track.

Comment: The document encoding and use of numeric character entity references have nothing to do with the content of either document (XML or XSLT), nor with the XSL processing; those are storage-only concerns. All characters are Unicode, regardless. How are you concluding that the output contains the character Â? What are the bytes?

Comment: FWIW, if you save a text document containing "at 39 °F" as a UTF-8 file, the hex dump will show `61 74 20 33 39 C2 A0 C2 B0 46`. So the problem may be with the application reading the file.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. Hmm yes that's interesting.

Comment: --UPDATE--

The first application displaying the transformed output incorrectly was the output window of the Treebeard tool itself. Then imports into Mariadb and Excel were bad.

I downloaded a different tool (Simple XSLT Transform 3.1), and this tool, with an unmodified XSLT file DOES display a lot of characters successfully, and I can open the file in Excel  and a lot of the characters are correct, BUT that's with Excel (PowerQuery) set to CodePage 1252(?!)

It looks as if maybe the tools are picking up the default codepage from the Windows env. and changing the output encoding.